# Move a row up or down within jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I would like to move a row up or down within a grid by grabbing it and moving it (similar to how netflix allows a user to reprioritze a movie selection in the user's queue). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a demo for dragging rows between tables on the [jqGrid Demos](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) site under:

`New in version 3.6` | `Drag and Drop Rows`

This is not exactly what you are asking for, but you might be able to use it as a starting point for your needs.

Comment: Thanks. I did see that, but it seems to focus on moving data from one grid to another. I only have one grid to display, so I just want to be able to move the row within that single grid.

Comment: (hit enter too soon on the previous post - not quite done. oops). 

One option that comes to mind would be to have a hidden column that the grid sorts by (the grid would not support sorting otherwise). I'm thinking I could add up/down icons, resetting the id of the row accordingly (and the row above/below it) and resort the grid programmatically.